# Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'serializeToString' on 'XMLSerializer': Failing to download an svg (created with D3.js) as png/pdf

Tags: javascript, django, d3.js, svg

I am trying to download a graph that I created with d3.js as an png (Any datatyp would do though), but I am failing gloriously.

I followed various questions on Stackoverflow which address similar issues, but still can't get it to work.

With different solutions I very often run into this error when debugging:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'serializeToString' on 'XMLSerializer': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

This is my code for my svg-graph:

```
var data = build
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 100},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// set the ranges
var y = d3.scaleBand()
          .range([height, 0])
          .padding(0.1);

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
          .range([0, width]);

// append the svg object to the body of the page
// append a 'group' element to 'svg'
// moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
var svg = d3.select(".svg-net-area").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  // format the data
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.buildings__net_leased_area = +d.buildings__net_leased_area;
  });

  // Scale the range of the data in the domains
  x.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){ return d.buildings__net_leased_area; })])
  y.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.buildings__name; }));
  //y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.buildings__net_leased_area; })]);

  // append the rectangles for the bar chart
  svg.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      //.attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.buildings__net_leased_area); })
      .attr("width", function(d) {return x(d.buildings__net_leased_area); } )
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.buildings__name); })
      .attr("height", y.bandwidth())
      .attr("fill", "#348496");

  // add the x Axis
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  // add the y Axis
  svg.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
```

And this is what I am trying:

```
 function svgDataURL(svg) {
         var svgAsXML = (new XMLSerializer).serializeToString(svg);
         return "data:image/svg+xml," + encodeURIComponent(svgAsXML);
       }

  function download(){
        var dataURL = svgDataURL(svg)
        var dl = document.createElement("a");
        document.body.appendChild(dl);
        dl.setAttribute("href", dataURL);
        dl.setAttribute("download", "test.svg");
        dl.click();
      }
```

I call this function in my django template.

I am trying to create a DataURL for my svg graph. Then I want to pass it to the download function. But I am not entirely sure what I am even doing here.

So if someone could help that would be very nice. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code, `svg` is a *D3 selection*. You cannot pass a D3 selection to `serializeToString`. Have a look at the error here:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var svgAsXML = (new XMLSerializer).serializeToString(svg);
console.log(svgAsXML)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg>
  <circle r="20" cx="100" cy="50"></circle>
</svg>
```

As you can see, [`serializeToString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLSerializer/serializeToString) requires a node:

> The Node to use as the root of the DOM tree or subtree for which to construct an XML representation.

Therefore, instead of passing a D3 selection, you have to pass the node. The easiest way to do that is using the D3 method `node()` on the selection:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var svgAsXML = (new XMLSerializer).serializeToString(svg.node());
console.log(svgAsXML)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg>
  <circle r="20" cx="100" cy="50"></circle>
</svg>
```

So, in your code, pass the node to the `svgDataUrl` function:

```
var dataURL = svgDataURL(svg.node())
```

Alternatively, pass the D3 selection to `svgDataUrl`, but use the node inside `serializeToString`, as I did above.

Comment: Gerardo, thank you so much, that is wonderful!! It solved the error. Now I can download the .svg file. Unfortunately it when I open up the file it is empty though... Would you happen to know why that could be?

Comment: No, I don't... the best idea is posting another question, with all the relevant information. By the way, what's the new value of `svgAsXML`?

Comment: the value is ```<g xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" transform="translate(100,20)"><rect class="bar" width="5.244670050761421" y="394.44444444444446" height="50" fill="#348496"/><rect class="bar" width="526.3857868020305" y="338.8888888888889" height="50" fill="#348496"/><rect class="bar" width="57.3502538071066" y="283.3333333333333" height="50" fill="#348496"/><rect class="bar" width="840" y="227.77777777777777" height="50" fill="#348496"/><rect class="bar" width="5.116751269035533" y="172.22222222222223" height="50" fill="#348496"/><rect class="bar"``` and this keeps on going...